# set condition on another model in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have Board,Tag,BoardsTag model that boards table keeps boards data,tags table keeps tags data and boards_tags table keeps the relation between board & tags.
now in BoardsController I want to find boards with specific tags I did something like this:

```
$boards = $this->Board->find('all',
    array(
            "conditions"=>'Tag.title'=>$tags,
        )
    );
```

but I have errors.please tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ContainableBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html):

```
class Board extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    /* etc. */
```

And in your controller:

```
$boards = $this->Board->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Tag.title' => $tags
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 1):

may be using ADHOC-Join can meet your needs.

```
$this->Board->find('all', array(
                        'joins' => array(
                            array(
                                'table' => 'boards_tags',
                                'alias' => 'BoardsTag',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                    'BoardsTag.board_id = Board.id'
                                ),
                            ),
                            array(
                                'table' => 'tags',
                                'alias' => 'Tag',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                    'Tag.id = BoardsTag.tag_id',
                                    'And' => array(
                                        'Tag.title LIKE' => '%' . $tags . '%'),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ));
```

Comment: tnx,but it returns all boards.

Comment: I have updated my answer (change `left` to `inner` join)